# .Popen a pdf then delete file once it is closed

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, delete-file

I need to .Popen a pdf, let my user view it, print it, do whatever they need to do with it, then once it is closed, delete the file.  Currently what I tried is this:

```
def open_file():
  try:
    subprocess.Popen(file_path, shell=True)
  except:
    print(exception)
  finally:
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
      os.remove(file_path)
      print("File successfully removed.")
```

What I need is something more like this:

```
def open_file():
  try:
    subprocess.Popen(file_path, shell=True)
  except:
    print(exception)
  finally:
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
      while file_path.IS_OPEN:
        sleep(1)
      if file_path.IS_NOT_OPEN:
        os.remove(file_path)
        print("File successfully removed.")
```

or something like that.  I'm still a novice, so I'm sure my syntax is wrong.  Is this possible?

I have found that if I put a sleep function before the os.remove of the first example, I get an error back saying it cannot delete an open file, whereas otherwise it somehow deletes before opening causing the open to error.  Can I make some sort of loop based on this first error that keeps checking if a file is open and when it is not, remove it?

Comment: you could copy the pdf in a temp drive, open the temp one and delete the source. At some point the temp one will be deleted when closing the session/rebooting

Comment: Okay, I am using a temp file but I read something that said "Developers should take care of their own clean up" in regards to temp files.  This is my first foray into temp files and how they work.

Comment: Which operating system are you on? You could do `Popen(file_path, shell=True).wait()` which will wait on the subprocess.... which might not work because sometimes a intermediate process starts the pdf reader and then exits, defeating your wait.

Comment: I am using Win10

Comment: That worked perfectly!

Comment: The wait? I'll write it up.

Comment: As a riff on @Jean-FrançoisFabre 's suggestion, there should be a way to use the win32 api CreateFile function with the FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE to make the temporary copy. Then this program could exit. I don't have the details, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you open the PDF reader, you don't wait for it to complete. You could wait until the program exits to try the delete. Several `subprocess` functions do this, but `run` is considering the modern way.

```
subprocess.run(file_path, shell=True)
```

This works if the subprocess is in fact the PDF reader. Sometimes an intermediate program runs the reader and then exits, spoiling this solution.

Comment: you can use `subprocess.call` then. No need for Popen. call will block too

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - good point. I think I'll change this to `run` as `call` is documented as the "older high level api".

Comment: ```run``` immediately gives me this error: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process", ```wait()``` is the only thing that has worked for me so far